# SQL developer licensing

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer, plsql-developer

SQL developer is free or do you require license for oracle database to use the sql or pl/sql developer? Also, Is it secure to connect to the oracle database since it connects to the db over a remote port right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should contact the vendor about licensing.

Comment: That's there, but I thought even some vendors would be here as well :)

Comment: There are many; however this is not an official outlet for vendor statements, and you should not trust advice presented here that you might later need to rely on in court.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Developer the client application is free of charge.  Of course, the Oracle database would need to be licensed in a way that allowed you to connect with any tool.

PL/SQL Developer is a completely different tool produced by a different company that you would need to license.

Define "secure".  Assuming a default database install, using any tool to connect to the database is secure in the sense that, say, the password isn't sent in clear text over the network.  But all the data is, by default, sent in clear text unless you configure Advanced Security.  But there are many, many ways that a database could be relatively secure or relatively insecure because there are many, many ways to set up security and many types of things that people may want to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

1. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/pricing-faq-085267.html

> Is Oracle SQL Developer free?
>   Yes.

`PL/SQL Developer` is another product, that is not free.

2. Other tools, even applications or application servers connect the database remotely. So yes, it is.

Answer (score 1):

We don't charge for SQL Developer.

If you want official support, you need a database licensed and covered by My Oracle Support.

It's more complicated than this, but it's effectively free.